# tag html onmouseover for prestashop

Tags: prestashop-1.6, onmouseover

i created a simple code html, for have the effect onmouseover in descriptions of products my e-commerce, i use prestashop, but when i paste and i save this code prestashop change and skyp a lot of tags.. this is html that i created:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<div id="sx">&nbsp;
<center>
<div id="wrapper">
<center>
<div id="content">
<center><br />
<br />
&nbsp;
<table align="center" border="0" width="700">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td align="center" rowspan="2" style="width: 20%; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><font color="#000000" face="Verdana" size="3"><img alt="Joomoda" onmouseover="document.mainpic.src='https://dstreet.pl/data/gfx/pictures/large/1/8/681_7.jpg'" src="https://dstreet.pl/data/gfx/pictures/large/1/8/681_7.jpg
" style="border: 1px solid rgb(68, 68, 68); width: 155px; height: 200px;" /> <img alt="Joomoda" onmouseover="document.mainpic.src='https://dstreet.pl/data/gfx/pictures/large/1/8/681_1.jpg'" src="https://dstreet.pl/data/gfx/pictures/large/1/8/681_1.jpg
" style="border: 1px solid rgb(68, 68, 68); width: 155px; height: 200px;" /><img alt="Joomoda" onmouseover="document.mainpic.src='https://dstreet.pl/data/gfx/pictures/large/1/8/681_5.jpg'" src="https://dstreet.pl/data/gfx/pictures/large/1/8/681_5.jpg
" style="border: 1px solid rgb(68, 68, 68); width: 155px; height: 200px;" /> </font></td>
   <td align="center" rowspan="2" style="width: 20%; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><img alt="Joomoda" onmouseover="document.mainpic.src='https://dstreet.pl/data/gfx/pictures/large/1/8/681_4.jpg'" src="https://dstreet.pl/data/gfx/pictures/large/1/8/681_4.jpg
" style="font-family: Verdana; border: 1px solid rgb(68, 68, 68); width: 155px; height: 200px;" /><img alt="Joomoda" onmouseover="document.mainpic.src='https://dstreet.pl/data/gfx/pictures/large/1/8/681_3.jpg'" src="https://dstreet.pl/data/gfx/pictures/large/1/8/681_3.jpg
" style="font-family: Verdana; border: 1px solid rgb(68, 68, 68); width: 155px; height: 200px;" /><img alt="Joomoda" onmouseover="document.mainpic.src='https://dstreet.pl/data/gfx/pictures/large/1/8/681_2.jpg'" src="https://dstreet.pl/data/gfx/pictures/large/1/8/681_2.jpg
" style="font-family: Verdana; border: 1px solid rgb(68, 68, 68); width: 155px; height: 200px;" /></td>
   <td align="center" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><font color="#000000" face="Verdana" size="3"><img align="absmiddle" name="mainpic" src="https://dstreet.pl/data/gfx/pictures/large/1/8/681_7.jpg" style="max-height: 612px; border-width: 4px; border-style: solid; margin: 2px; width: 435px; height: 560px;" /></font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td align="center" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); height: 40px; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); vertical-align: middle;"><span style="font-size:26px;"><strong>FELPA UOMO BX0060</strong></span></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</center>
</div>
</center>
</div>
</center>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is html code that return me prestashop when i save:

```html
<table align="center" border="0" style="width: 700px;" class=" cke_show_border">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2" style="background-color: #000000; width: 20%;"><img alt="Joomoda" data-cke-saved-src="https://dstreet.pl/data/gfx/pictures/large/1/8/681_7.jpg
" src="https://dstreet.pl/data/gfx/pictures/large/1/8/681_7.jpg
" style="border: 1px solid #444444; height: 200px; width: 155px;" /> <img alt="Joomoda" data-cke-saved-src="https://dstreet.pl/data/gfx/pictures/large/1/8/681_1.jpg
" src="https://dstreet.pl/data/gfx/pictures/large/1/8/681_1.jpg
" style="border: 1px solid #444444; height: 200px; width: 155px;" /><img alt="Joomoda" data-cke-saved-src="https://dstreet.pl/data/gfx/pictures/large/1/8/681_5.jpg
" src="https://dstreet.pl/data/gfx/pictures/large/1/8/681_5.jpg
" style="border: 1px solid #444444; height: 200px; width: 155px;" /></td>
<td rowspan="2" style="background-color: #000000; width: 20%;"><img alt="Joomoda" data-cke-saved-src="https://dstreet.pl/data/gfx/pictures/large/1/8/681_4.jpg
" src="https://dstreet.pl/data/gfx/pictures/large/1/8/681_4.jpg
" style="border: 1px solid #444444; font-family: verdana; height: 200px; width: 155px;" /><img alt="Joomoda" data-cke-saved-src="https://dstreet.pl/data/gfx/pictures/large/1/8/681_3.jpg
" src="https://dstreet.pl/data/gfx/pictures/large/1/8/681_3.jpg
" style="border: 1px solid #444444; font-family: verdana; height: 200px; width: 155px;" /><img alt="Joomoda" data-cke-saved-src="https://dstreet.pl/data/gfx/pictures/large/1/8/681_2.jpg
" src="https://dstreet.pl/data/gfx/pictures/large/1/8/681_2.jpg
" style="border: 1px solid #444444; font-family: verdana; height: 200px; width: 155px;" /></td>
<td style="background-color: #000000;"><img data-cke-saved-src="https://dstreet.pl/data/gfx/pictures/large/1/8/681_7.jpg" src="https://dstreet.pl/data/gfx/pictures/large/1/8/681_7.jpg" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 4px; height: 560px; margin: 2px; max-height: 612px; width: 435px;" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #ffffff; border-color: #000000; height: 40px; vertical-align: middle;"><span style="font-size: 26px;"><strong>FELPA UOMO BX0060</strong></span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

can help me please create a code similar this that will compatible with prestashop please?

Thans

Andrea

Comment: where are you trying to "save" this?

Comment: in description of product in prestashop

Comment: here you can see result

[link](http://www.joomoda.com/felpe-uomo/1591-felpa-uomo-djm681.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn off the HTML Purifier in the menu Preferences -> General.
This will only prevent from removing some code, but it still won't accept the onmouseover to be in the field. To achieved this, the best way is to also override the function isCleanHtml in the class Validate. create the file override/classes/Validate.php with this content:

```
<?php
class Validate extends ValidateCore
{
    public static function isCleanHtml($html, $allow_iframe = false)
    {
        $events = 'onmousedown|onmousemove|onmmouseup|onmouseout|onload|onunload|onfocus|onblur|onchange';
        $events .= '|onsubmit|ondblclick|onclick|onkeydown|onkeyup|onkeypress|onmouseenter|onmouseleave|onerror|onselect|onreset|onabort|ondragdrop|onresize|onactivate|onafterprint|onmoveend';
        $events .= '|onafterupdate|onbeforeactivate|onbeforecopy|onbeforecut|onbeforedeactivate|onbeforeeditfocus|onbeforepaste|onbeforeprint|onbeforeunload|onbeforeupdate|onmove';
        $events .= '|onbounce|oncellchange|oncontextmenu|oncontrolselect|oncopy|oncut|ondataavailable|ondatasetchanged|ondatasetcomplete|ondeactivate|ondrag|ondragend|ondragenter|onmousewheel';
        $events .= '|ondragleave|ondragover|ondragstart|ondrop|onerrorupdate|onfilterchange|onfinish|onfocusin|onfocusout|onhashchange|onhelp|oninput|onlosecapture|onmessage|onmouseup|onmovestart';
        $events .= '|onoffline|ononline|onpaste|onpropertychange|onreadystatechange|onresizeend|onresizestart|onrowenter|onrowexit|onrowsdelete|onrowsinserted|onscroll|onsearch|onselectionchange';
        $events .= '|onselectstart|onstart|onstop';

        if (preg_match('/<[\s]*script/ims', $html) || preg_match('/('.$events.')[\s]*=/ims', $html) || preg_match('/.*script\:/ims', $html)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!$allow_iframe && preg_match('/<[\s]*(i?frame|form|input|embed|object)/ims', $html)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Then delete the file cache/class_index.php. And try to save it again.

This function content will prevent the same code as before, except now won't search for the onmouseover.

Comment: Hi and thank you for help, i created file php and i deleated file cache /override/classes/cache/index.php,
the first attempt he told me the content of the description is invalid, after which I tried to save again, but now, when I save, delete directly the html code created and leaves only the initial part, created with the normal editor.
Any idea ?